Creating mocks for images with Jest
I have a function that returns an array of objects with a title and an image:
import fire from 'assets/svg/fire.svg';
import water from './img/water.svg';
import wind from './img/wind.svg';


const getConfig = (gender) => {
   return [
       {
         title: 'first title',
         image: fire
       },
       {
         title: 'second title',
         image: gender === 'male' ? wind : water
       }
     
   ]
}

And I want to create tests to check for the correct file name. For example:
expect(optionsData[0].title).toBe('first title');
expect(optionsData[0].image).toBe('fire.svg');

Didn't find the correct solution.
The one with creating
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';

in the fileMock.ts will always return the same string, and it is useless if the image depends on the gender.
The solution form question How Can I Manually Mock Svg's in my Tests? doesn't work because I get the string from the fileMock. If I delete those files, the result is:
Expected: "fire.webp"
Received: "2n��-3��Dj�+��jŊ�aq���"

or
- Expected  - 1
+ Received  + 2

- fire.svg
+ svg>
+


This question is similar to: How Can I Manually Mock Svg's in my Tests?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@evolutionxbox updated

See Mocking CSS Modules documentation:

If moduleNameMapper cannot fulfill your requirements, you can use Jest's transform config option to specify how assets are transformed. For example, a transformer that returns the basename of a file (such that require('logo.jpg'); returns 'logo') can be written as:

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
    return {
      code: `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(sourcePath))};`,
    };
  },
};

jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js',
  },
};

In this way, we can return different value for different image module.
For your question, see below example:
$ tree 
.
|-- assets
|   |-- fire.svg
|   |-- water.svg
|   `-- wind.svg
|-- fileTransformer.js
|-- index.js
`-- index.test.js

1 directory, 6 files

index.js:
import fire from './assets/fire.svg';
import water from './assets/water.svg';
import wind from './assets/wind.svg';

const getConfig = (gender) => {
  return [
    {
      title: 'first title',
      image: fire,
    },
    {
      title: 'second title',
      image: gender === 'male' ? wind : water,
    },
  ];
};

export default getConfig;

index.test.js:
import getConfig from './';

describe('78711697', () => {
  test('should return correct if gender is male', () => {
    const conf = getConfig('male');
    expect(conf).toEqual([
      { title: 'first title', image: 'fire.svg' },
      { title: 'second title', image: 'wind.svg' },
    ]);
  });

  test('should return correct if gender is female', () => {
    const conf = getConfig('female');
    expect(conf).toEqual([
      { title: 'first title', image: 'fire.svg' },
      { title: 'second title', image: 'water.svg' },
    ]);
  });
});

fileTransformer.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
    return {
      code: `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(sourcePath))};`,
    };
  },
};

jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
  ],
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/stackoverflow/78711697/fileTransformer.js',
  },
};

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/78711697/index.test.js
  78711697
    √ should return correct if gender is male (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    √ should return correct if gender is female                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.802 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

